# LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item

Tags: bibtex, errors, warnings

I am writing my thesis using a LaTeX template. When I tried to import my references, I got the following errors when I texifyed my `thesis.tex`:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: thesis.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: 0_frontmatter/abstract.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: 0_frontmatter/acknowledgement.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: 1_introduction/introduction.aux
The style file: aaai.bst
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file thesis.aux
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Chang04"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Madhavan07"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Liu03"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Zhai05"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Zhai06"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Zhao05"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Zhao06"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Simon05"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Miao09"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Liu05"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Zhu06"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Crescenzi01"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Chang01a"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Wang03"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Arasu03"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Liu10"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Cai03"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Weng11"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Weng12"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Lu07"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Lu11"
(There was 1 error message)

Command Line:   texify.exe --src "C:\Users\dweng\Dropbox\My PhD Thesis\thesis.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\dweng\Dropbox\My PhD Thesis

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
entering extended mode
("C:/Users/dweng/Dropbox/My PhD Thesis/thesis.tex"
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2012-05-30, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2012-05-30, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Users\dweng\Dropbox\My PhD Thesis\Latex/Classes/PhDthesisPSnPDF.cls"
Document Class: Latex/Classes/PhDthesisPSnPDF 2007/09/06 v2 PhD thesis class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\book.cls"
Document Class: book 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\bk12.clo"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amssymb.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amsfonts.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\dvips.def"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\caption\caption.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\caption\caption3.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fancyhdr\fancyhdr.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\eucal.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.sty"
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\bblopts.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\english.ldf"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.def")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\color.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\color.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\dvipsnam.def"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\footmisc\footmisc.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\multicol.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tocbibind\tocbibind.sty"

Package tocbibind Note: Using chapter style headings, unless overridden.

) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\nomencl\nomencl.sty")
Writing nomenclature file thesis.nlo
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hyperref.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\auxhook.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\pd1enc.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\backref.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ltxmisc\url.sty"))

Package hyperref Message: Driver: hdvips.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hdvips.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\pdfmark.def"

Package hyperref Warning: You have enabled option `breaklinks'.
(hyperref)                But driver `hdvips.def' does not suppport this.
(hyperref)                Expect trouble with the link areas of broken links.

)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\epsfig.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty")))
\@input{Latex/Macros/MacroFile1.aux}
("C:\Users\dweng\Dropbox\My PhD Thesis\Latex/Macros/MacroFile1.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\jknappen\mathrsfs.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\dstroke\dsfont.sty")

LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [pdftex].

("C:\Users\dweng\Dropbox\My PhD Thesis\thesis.aux"
("C:\Users\dweng\Dropbox\My PhD Thesis\0_frontmatter/abstract.aux")
("C:\Users\dweng\Dropbox\My PhD Thesis\0_frontmatter/acknowledgement.aux")
("C:\Users\dweng\Dropbox\My PhD Thesis\1_introduction/introduction.aux"

LaTeX Warning: Label `fig1' multiply defined.

)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty"))
("C:\Users\dweng\Dropbox\My PhD Thesis\thesis.out")
("C:\Users\dweng\Dropbox\My PhD Thesis\thesis.out") <qub.png> [1
\FN@pp@footnotehinttrue 
] ("C:\Users\dweng\Dropbox\My PhD Thesis\0_frontmatter/abstract.tex" [2]
[3]) [4
\FN@pp@footnotehinttrue 
] ("C:\Users\dweng\Dropbox\My PhD Thesis\0_frontmatter/acknowledgement.tex"
[1]) [2
\FN@pp@footnotehinttrue 
] ("C:\Users\dweng\Dropbox\My PhD Thesis\thesis.toc") [3] [4]
("C:\Users\dweng\Dropbox\My PhD Thesis\thesis.lof"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsb.fd")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\jknappen\ursfs.fd")) [5] [6]
("C:\Users\dweng\Dropbox\My PhD Thesis\thesis.lot") [7] [8]
("C:\Users\dweng\Dropbox\My PhD Thesis\1_introduction/introduction.tex"
Chapter 1.

LaTeX Warning: Citation `Chang04' on page 1 undefined on input line 18.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Madhavan07' on page 1 undefined on input line 18.

<1_introduction/figures/abebooks_query_interface.eps>
<1_introduction/figures/abebooks_two_records_prefix.eps> [1]
<1_introduction/figures/two_plates_examples.eps> [2]

LaTeX Warning: Citation `Liu03' on page 3 undefined on input line 47.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Zhai05' on page 3 undefined on input line 47.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Zhai06' on page 3 undefined on input line 47.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Zhao05' on page 3 undefined on input line 47.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Zhao06' on page 3 undefined on input line 47.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Simon05' on page 3 undefined on input line 47.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Miao09' on page 3 undefined on input line 47.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Liu05' on page 3 undefined on input line 47.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Zhu06' on page 3 undefined on input line 47.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Crescenzi01' on page 3 undefined on input line 47.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Chang01a' on page 3 undefined on input line 47.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Wang03' on page 3 undefined on input line 47.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Arasu03' on page 3 undefined on input line 47.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Liu10' on page 3 undefined on input line 47.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Liu10' on page 3 undefined on input line 47.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Cai03' on page 3 undefined on input line 47.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Crescenzi01' on page 3 undefined on input line 47.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Chang01a' on page 3 undefined on input line 47.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Wang03' on page 3 undefined on input line 47.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Arasu03' on page 3 undefined on input line 47.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Liu03' on page 3 undefined on input line 47.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Zhai05' on page 3 undefined on input line 47.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Zhai06' on page 3 undefined on input line 47.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Zhao05' on page 3 undefined on input line 47.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Zhao06' on page 3 undefined on input line 47.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Simon05' on page 3 undefined on input line 47.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Miao09' on page 3 undefined on input line 47.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Liu05' on page 3 undefined on input line 47.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Zhai05' on page 3 undefined on input line 47.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Zhai06' on page 3 undefined on input line 47.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Simon05' on page 3 undefined on input line 47.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Liu05' on page 3 undefined on input line 47.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Zhu06' on page 3 undefined on input line 47.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Zhao06' on page 3 undefined on input line 49.


Underfull \vbox (badness 3579) has occurred while \output is active [3]

LaTeX Warning: Citation `Cai03' on page 4 undefined on input line 55.

[4] [5]

LaTeX Warning: Citation `Weng11' on page 6 undefined on input line 67.

[6] <1_introduction/figures/abebooks_two_records_prefix.eps>

LaTeX Warning: Citation `Weng11' on page 7 undefined on input line 81.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Weng12' on page 7 undefined on input line 81.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Lu07' on page 7 undefined on input line 81.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Lu11' on page 7 undefined on input line 81.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Wang03' on page 7 undefined on input line 81.

[7]

LaTeX Warning: Citation `Cai03' on page 8 undefined on input line 83.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Weng11' on page 8 undefined on input line 83.

<1_introduction/figures/annotation_flow_chart.eps>) [8] [9]
("C:\Users\dweng\Dropbox\My PhD Thesis\thesis.bbl"
("C:\Users\dweng\Dropbox\My PhD Thesis\thesis.brf")

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.3 \end{thebibliography}

?
```

So how to solve these warnings and especially how to solve the 'missing `\item`' one. I know the problem must occurs in the bibliography section. The content of my bibtex file is like:

```
@article{Abdessalem10,
  author    = {Talel Abdessalem and
               Bogdan Cautis and
               Nora Derouiche},
  title     = {ObjectRunner: Lightweight, Targeted Extraction and Querying
               of Structured Web Data},
  journal   = {PVLDB},
  volume    = {3},
  number    = {2},
  year      = {2010},
  pages     = {1585-1588},
  ee        = {http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/$\sim$vldb2010/proceedings/files/papers/D18.pdf},
  bibsource = {DBLP, http://dblp.uni-trier.de}
}
```

I am using the following code:

```
    \bibliographystyle{aaai}%{CUEPhDbiblio-url}
    \bibliography{12_backmatter/myrefs} % adjust this to fit your BibTex file
```

I am using Winedt 6 & MikTex2.9 x64, and after I ran BibTex in 'Tex', the following errors popped up:

```
Command Line:   bibtex.exe "thesis"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\dweng\Dropbox\My PhD Thesis

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: thesis.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: 0_frontmatter/abstract.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: 0_frontmatter/acknowledgement.aux
The style file: aaai.bst
I found no \citation commands---while reading file thesis.aux
Database file #1: 12_backmatter/myrefs.bib
(There was 1 error message)
```

Comment: The best, and most general, way to find and solve problems like these is by constructing a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).  You can then edit your question to include it so that others can help you locate and solve the problem(s).

Comment: I don't think `aaai.bst` is not a standard file; it would be helpful if you told us where it came from.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: It sounds very much like there's a problem with the instruction `\bibliography{12_backmatter/myrefs}`. Have you checked that (i) your bib file is named `myrefs.bib` and (ii) that the bib file is located in a subdirectory (relative to your main tex file) named "12_backmatter"? Have you tried moving `myrefs.bib` to the directory where your main tex file is located and then rerunning latex/bibtex/latex/latex -- this time *without* the `12_backmatter/` substring in the `\bibliography` statement?

Comment: my bib file is named 'myrefs.bib', and it is located in '12_backmatter', I have checked that. '12_backmatter' is located in the main folder where 'thesis.tex' is placed.

Comment: @jon:the template is acquired from my friend, he was using it to write his thesis, and so I was directly coping it from him, and of course the folder contains files he generated and LaTex generated. And I didn't remove those LaTex generated files. These laTex generated files caused problems? I am not sure.

Comment: Quite possibly, if you have used some of the same file names as he has!  I would delete all files but your `.tex`, `.cls`, `.sty`, `.bib`, and `.bst` (and maybe things like `.def` if you have them), and then try to compile with the normal: `latex`, `bibtex`, `latex`, `latex` sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Since this only happened when you tried to import your references, you should carefully check your BibTeX file for non-LaTeX friendly content.
For example, in the citation you listed, I can see a URL with `$\sim$`. This is probably causing you a problem and needs to be removed.
Try to make a new BibTeX file and add your references one-by-one to check which one has problems and which not.

Comment: does it have something to do with the code i am using? like:\bibliographystyle{aaai}%{CUEPhDbiblio-url}
\bibliography{12_backmatter/myrefs} % adjust this to fit your BibTex file

Comment: The `$\sim$` will not cause a problem from BibTeX's point of view.

Comment: I guess the problem maybe that your bibtex compilation didn't generate any correct items, thus the bibliography section is now empty. So, LaTeX think you are trying to create a list environment without any items ... this is what I can guess to the best of my knowledge!

Comment: @jon, true. But it might be stopping LaTeX somehow from processing the bibliography items. The error of missing \item is usually related to empty listing environment, his bibliography list in this case. So for some reason, the list didn't get populated correctly.

Comment: Maybe.  It looks to me like he hasn't run `bibtex` on the file.  But the `$\sim$` can be put in a bibliography entry just fine, AFAIK (though I wouldn't put one in a URL).

Comment: I didn't think about not running bibtex problem as he will see the above errors anyway the first time he tries to compile his file. Since thesis.aux will not have any references yet ...

Comment: @Bichoy, _something_ (a botched BibTeX run?) did create the file the bibliography is trying to process, probably empty. Or OP did not only add the bibliography, but inadvertently messed up some other environment (yes, I've spent hours looking at the wrong environments, only to find a stupid typo from an editor command getting into the file in some totally unrelated place).

Answer (score 2):

You could try a couple of things:

1) Make sure you are citing correctly, i.e. `\cite{authorlabel}`.  e.g: `\cite{Abdessalem10}`.

2) Try putting your .bib file in the same directory as your main file, and point to it directly.  e.g:

```
\bibliography{myrefs}
```

3) If using TeXnicCenter, make sure you have checked the `UsesBibTeX` option in your project properties.

Comment: I was facing the same problem in IEEE Transaction's paper. I was having the following lines:

    \bibliography{IEEEabrv}
    \bibliography{Review_PAMI}

The first line is IEEE database for abbreviations and second contain my references. In my case first line was creating problem. Once I commented the first line it worked for me.